# Answer a question in a popup window

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that I want to use to exicute a .exe file. The exe runs but it pops up a windows needing some information. How can I file in the popup with the correct information? The servername.domain is the server address that needs to be put in the popup. I thought that this was the syntax to populate the popup but its not working. Any help would be great.

```
SetupCodeGroup.exe servername.domain
```

Comment: WOW! No one has an idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found that you can not do what you want to do with a batch file. when i ran into a simaler problem i used vbscript sendkeys method. if you google that you should be able to do what you want.

and for your case i would have a batch file as a bass to run the vbscrit program you write to fill in the info in the .exe

somthing like this for the batch
(if you do copy and past this be sure to take out the comments (//)  )

```
@echo off
set reapet=100   // just setting varibles to be used in the delay loop
set con=1
set time=0

start (your .exe)  //starts your EXE

:begin
set /a time=%time%+%con%
if %time%==%reapet% goto:startvb        // this makes a delay so that we can be sure your     
goto:begin                              // computer fully started the .exe :)

:startvb
cls
start your (vbscript)               // this starts your vbscript

cls
echo Done                           // tells you the batch file is done
pause
```

i hope this helps.